# Application to accept arguments while running

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using visual studio 2008 and MFC. I accept arguments using a subclass of CCommandLineInfo and overriding ParseParam().

Now I want to pass these arguments to the application while running. For example "test.exe /start" and then to type in the console "test.exe /initialize" to be initialized again.

is there any way to do that?

Edit 1: Some clarifications. My program starts with "test.exe /start". I want to type "test.exe /initialize" and initialize the one and only running process (without closing/opening). And by initialize I mean to read a different XML file, to change some values of the interface and other things.

Comment: Possibly have the program start a new process of itself and terminate the old one when it receives "test.exe /initialize"? Don't really know much about what you can do with MFC applications. Alternatively, rather than truly "reinitializing", you might be able to take all the global variables you started with, set them to their original values, and return to the start of `main()`.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but I want to do this because my application starts some piece of machine that takes some time to initialize. So I don't want to terminate the process, just to initialize it again.

Comment: So could you store the initial state of all variables in the application when it starts, and set them back to that initial state when sending "initialize"?

Comment: I don't think so because initialization is done by an XML file that changes every time.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you could have your application run as two processes or threads? One main/initial one that would start up your piece of machine, and the other one that would do everything else and would be restarted/reinitialized by the main one when you enter "test.exe /initialize" or whatever in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of an easy way to accomplish what you're asking about.

However, you could develop your application to specifically receive commands, and given those commands take any actions you wanted based upon receiving them.  Since you're already using MFC, you can do this rather easily.  Create a Window (HWND) for your application and register it.  It doesn't have to be visible (this won't necessarily make you application a GUI application).  Implement a [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and define specific messages that you will receive based on `WM_USER + <xxx>`.

Answer (score 0):

First and obvious question is why you want to have threads, instead of processes.

You may use `GetCommandLine` and `CommandLineToArgvW` to get the fully formatted command line. Detect the arguments, and the call `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecute` passing /*watever* to spawn the process. You may also want to use `GetModuleBaseName` to get the name of your own EXE.

Comment: who said anything about threads? The problem is that I want to pass the arguments to the running process.

Comment: Pass arguments to a RUNNING process? You need to use one of the IPC mechanism: Pipes, mail-slots, shared-memory, or Windows function SendMessage/PostMessage etc.

Comment: Your question is vague - you need to run multiple processes or not?